# Why am I getting a syntax error for this conditional statement?

Tags: python, python-3.x, lambda, syntax-error, map-function

I've recently been practicing using `map()` in Python 3.5.2, and when I tried to run the module it said the comma separating the function and the `iterable` was a `SyntaxError`. Here's the code:

```
eng_swe = {"merry":"god", "christmas":"jul", "and":"och", "happy":"gott",
       "new":"nytt", "year":"år"}

def map_translate(l):
    """Translates English words into Swedish using the dictionary above."""

    return list(map(lambda x: eng_swe[x] if x in eng_swe.keys(), l))
```

I noticed that if I eliminate the conditional statement like this:

```
return list(map(lambda x: eng_swe[x], l))
```

it works fine, but it sacrifices the ability to avoid attempting to add items to the list that aren't in the dictionary. Interestingly enough, there also weren't any problems when I tried using a conditional statement with `reduce()`, as shown here:

```
from functools import reduce

def reduce_max_in_list(l):
    """Returns maximum integer in list using the 'reduce' function."""

    return reduce(lambda x, y: x if x > y else y, l)
```

Yes, I know I could do the exact same thing more cleanly and easily with a list comprehension, but I consider it worth my time to at least learn how to use `map()` correctly, even if I end up never using it again.

Comment: Ternary operators require an `else` condition.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're getting the `SyntaxError` because you're using a conditional expression without supplying the `else` clause which is mandatory.

[The grammar](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#conditional-expressions) for conditional expressions (i.e `if` statements in an expression form) ***always*** includes an `else` clause:

```
conditional_expression ::=  or_test ["if" or_test "else" expression]
                                                    ^^
```

In your `reduce` example you **do** supply it and, as a result, no errors are being raised.

Answer (score 4):

In your first example, you don't specify what should be returned if the condition *isn't* true.  Since python *can't* yield nothing from an expression, that is a syntax error.  e.g:

```
a if b  # SyntaxError.
a if b else c  # Ok.
```

<sup>You might argue that it could be useful to implicitly yield `None` in this case, but I doubt that a proposal of that sort would get any traction within the community... (I wouldn't vote for it ;-)</sup>

Answer (score 1):

While the others' explanations of why your code is causing a `SyntaxError` are completely accurate, the goal of my answer is to aid you in your goal "to at least learn how to use map() correctly."

Your use of `map` in this context does not make much sense. As you noted in your answer it would be much cleaner if you used a list comprehension:

```
[eng_swe[x] for x in l if x in eng_swe]
```

As you can see, this looks awfully similar to your map expression, minus some of the convolution. Generally, this is a sign that you're using `map` incorrectly. `map(lambda...` is pretty much a code smell. (Note that I am saying this as an ardent supporter of the use of `map` in Python. I know many people think it should never be used, but I am not one of those people, as long as it is used properly.)

So, you might be wondering, what is an example of a good time to use `map`? Well, one use case I can think of off the top of my head is converting a list of `str`s to `int`s. For example, if I am reading a table of data stored in a file, I might do:

```
with open('my_file.txt', 'r') as f:
    data = [map(int, line.split(' ')) for line in f]
```

Which would leave me with a 2d-array of `int`s, perfect for further manipulation or analysis. What makes this a better use of `map` than your code is that it uses a built-in function. I am not writing a lambda expressly to be used by map (as this is a sign that you should use a list comprehension).

Getting back to your code, however... if you want to write your code functionally, you should really be using [`filter`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#filter), which is just as important to know as `map`.

```
map(lambda x: eng_swe[x], filter(lambda x: eng_swe.get(x), l))
```

Note that I was unable to get rid of the `map(lambda...` code smell in my version, but at least I broke it down into smaller parts. The `filter` finds the words that can be translated and the `map` performs the actual translation. (Still, in this case, a list comprehension is probably better.) I hope that this explanation helps you more than it confuses you in your quest to write Python code functionally.

Comment: I appreciate it. I searched for a long time for a guide on how to use conditional statements but could never find one, hence this mistake.